# what binary value would attacker search for in wireshark to detect TCP segments?

Tags: tcp, wireshark

If an attacker had to write code to automatically detect TCP segments that contain data based on the binary value of the flags field, what binary value would they search for?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to look for the size of the payload, which also appears in the TCP header, but if he's looking at the `flags` field then he would probably look for the `PSH` flag (0x08). `(flags & 0x08 = 0x08)`.

Note that it is not mandatory for a payload to be flagged with `PSH` but it is common practice today.

Comment: You help is highly appreciable I am looking for the binary value.